# Cant find Unbalanced parenthesis error?

Tags: syntax, erlang

I have some Erlang code and Emacs is telling me that I have "Unbalanced parenthesis", but I can't figure what is wrong... Here is the code:

```
    receive
    {connect, Client} ->
        NewPid = spawn_link(fun() -> game_loop(0,0)),
        Client ! NewPid,
        handle_connect()
    end.
```

The error is at the row starting with NewPid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `end` after `game_loop(0,0)` in order to correctly completely define an anonymous function. The snippet should therefore look as follows:

```
receive
{connect, Client} ->
    NewPid = spawn_link(fun() -> game_loop(0,0) end),
    Client ! NewPid,
    handle_connect()
end.
```

Comment: Thank you! This drove me crazy!!